# Big Query - Adwords - AuthenticationError.NOT_ADS_USER

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I am trying to set up a data extract in BigQuery to pull data from a Google Ads Account. But I keep getting Auth errors (AuthenticationError.NOT_ADS_USER) when the extract tries starting pulling data.

```
<ApiError><type>AuthenticationError.NOT_ADS_USER</type><trigge
```

What did I do?-

- Set up Big Query and the data extract (as depicted here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer)
- Invited and added the same email address that big query is using to the Google Ads account with read access level (at first) and then standard access level when the problem persisted.

Is there something that I missed, that I have to enable/accept/configure in order for Big query extract to be able to pull the data from Google Ads?

Thanks,

p.s I have another extract in the same big query account with a different Google Ads account that is working, I recall have followed the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to remove and add the user account that you are using to access Google Ads. It's usually related to permissions related issue. Have you followed the steps mentioned here?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer#required_permissions

If yes, try remove and add again as suggested on both Google Ads and GCP. If it's not working, try creating a case with Google Cloud support team if you have that service enabled if not your marketing folks might have connections with Google to help you out.